# Call attr_accessor with child's method from parent class

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'd like to define a list of class attributes in a separate method or constant, so I could use the list several times in my code.

```
attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
```

doesn't do the job because: **a)** it's hard to retrieve a list of attributes from results of `attr_accessor` call (a bunch of setters and getters); and **b)** I need to put some metadata in my list of attributes. Moving the list to a constant does the job, because now I can do what I want with the list and still pass an array of symbols to `attr_accessor`. E.g.:

```
class A
  FIELDS = {a:'field a', b:'field b'}

  def self.field_names
    FIELDS.keys
  end

  attr_accessor *field_names
end
```

But I want to do this in a lot of similar classes, so to keep it DRY I have to move all repeating code like `self.field_names` and `attr_accessor *field_names` to a parent class. But this doesn't work:

```
class A
  FIELDS = {a:'field a', b:'field b'}

  def self.field_names
    FIELDS.keys
  end

  attr_accessor *field_names
end

class B < A
  FIELDS = {c: 'field c'}
end
```

because `attr_accessor` still receives A's method. Can I do this without fiddling with core `Class`?

Is there any way to call attr_accessor with child class' method from parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `attr_accessor` is still inescapably called upon loading class `A`. At this point class `B` does not yet (fully) exist, so it can't alter the constant.

You can, for example, defer creation of instance methods until an actual instance is created (I'm not too fond of this solution).

```
class A
  FIELDS = {a:'field a', b:'field b'}

  def initialize
    self.class.class_eval do
      attr_accessor *field_names
    end
  end

  def self.field_names
    self.const_get(:FIELDS).keys
  end

end

class B < A
  FIELDS = {c: 'field c'}
end

b = B.new
b.methods() # => [:c, :c=, ...
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks Sergio!

Comment: Wait, what is so bad about this solution? What alternative do we have?

Comment: Maybe instead of an initializer the line `attr_accessor *field_names` could be moved to B, right after the FIELDS line? That way each subclass would define accessors only once, and it would still use subclass-specific fields?

Comment: This means I have to repeat the line `attr_accessor *field_names` in each subclass. Which is not DRY. What is lesser evil between the two (repating yourself and calling `attr_accessor` from initializer)?